# How to get Foobar to be as WinAmp'y as possible?

Tags: audio, user-interface, media-player, winamp, foobar2000

I want to switch away from the terrible memory-eating monster that is WinAmp, and foobar2000 keeps coming up as an alternative. However, it's myriad plug-ins and weird UI are kind of daunting to me. What can/should I do to a cleam foobar installation to get it to behave sort-of like WinAmp?